# What is V_x in the following circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

[image]

Hi what is V_x

I think it's 12 volts.

Computer program does not agree with me.

Comment: Nope, *your load is 12V* so your source , Vx must be bigger, try again

Comment: You have to find the current and voltage across each resistor. Then, you will be able to find Vx

Comment: You should be able to calculate (well, Tony saved you the trouble) the voltage across your \$12\:\Omega\$ resistor and from that you can certainly now figure out the current in that resistor, too. Those currents can be added and must go through the remaining \$2\:\Omega\$ and \$3\:\Omega\$ resistors -- which are effectively in series with each other (allowing you to erase the two of them and replace either one of them with their sum.) From there, you should be very near the answer.

Comment: The OP might be thinking Vx is a voltmeter, then his answer is correct, however the symbol is for a power supply or a "Voltage source"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go through several step to find \$ V_x\$.

1. Find \$V_{R1}\$. You can easily find it thanks to *Ohm's law*
2. Since you know \$V_{R1}\$, \$I_{R2}\$ come easy to find.
3. It is now possible to know how much current the power supply provide to the circuit. *(Kirchhoff's current law)*
4. Knowing that amount of current, you can calculate \$V_{R3}\$ and \$V_{R4}\$
5. Voltage sum of the circuit has to be zero, you can now determine \$V_{x}\$. *(Kirchhoff's voltage law)*

I hope it helps :)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJveX1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Using Kirchhoff's Law I got 3 amps running through R4                    Since R4 V_x and R3 are in series everything there has 3 amps

Comment: This is correct so far

Comment: Using Kirchhoff's Law I got 3 amps running through R4                   
 Since R4 V_x and R3 are in series everything there has 3 amps

Vr3 = 9
Vr4 = 6

Vr2 =12 

Using KVL I got -6-12-9 =V_x

V_x = -27V ??????

Comment: I can't figure out how to use this comment section it's annoying

Comment: Vx-6-12-9 = 0 then Vx = 27V ;)

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh thank you so much for real

Comment: @Jay You are welcome ;) Don't forgot to accept the answer if you have no more question

Comment: KVL: Vx - V3 - V2 - V4 =0

Comment: after practise you will be able to do this in a few seconds in your head